# Create additional partitions to an existing Postgres table

Tags: postgresql, database-administration

I have a table with 1T of data and the table has some 50 partition. Each partition holds a week of data. However I am looking to create additional partitions to hold additional weekly of data. To do this, I am creating a table and attaching with the main table. The command is as follows:

```
Create table test.2023w327
   partition of test.main_table
      For values from (‘2023-07-03’) To (‘2023-07-10’);
```

My question is this a right way to do it. Also would this lock the table? I don’t know yet how much time this will table since the table holds 1T of data. Suggestions please.

Comment: Yes, this is the right way to do it. But it's pretty hard to believe that you didn't test this yourself...

Comment: Hi Frank, thanks for the response. Yes I did tested it out. However after 8 some mins of processing I cancelled the statement as I think it locks the table. Thus was wondering is there another approach to this.

Comment: Yes, it locks the table.  But the lock should be extremely short.  Presumably the problem is not how long it holds the lock, but how long it takes to acquire the lock in the first place.

Comment: So in this case - if there are end-users processing their script, the system will wait for their processing to be finished before placing the lock. I believe this what you meant when stating “how long it takes to acquire the lock in the first place”. Thanks

Comment: If you create the table as a stand-alone table first, then attach it as a partition later, it will still need a lock, but it is a weaker lock.  That may or may not be weak enough to avoid the problem, depending on what the other processes are doing.

Comment: Got it. So guess recommended time is to run off hours where the flow is less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is a correct way to create a partition for a range partitioned table, except that you forgot to double quote the table name (which starts with a number). However, it will require a short `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock on the partitioned table.

To perform that operation with a lock that is less strong, you can

- ```
  CREATE TABLE test.part_2023w327 (LIKE test.main_table);
  ```
- ```
  ALTER TABLE test.main_table
     ATTACH PARTITION test.part_2023w327
        FOR VALUES FROM (‘2023-07-03’) TO (‘2023-07-10’);
  ```

Comment: The problem comes when you have an overflow partition with maxvalue for the next year (for example 2024xx), you must to make a transaction with the detach for the maxvalue partition and the create of the same period partition.  and move the data

Comment: The `ALTER TABLE` snippet is missing the `part_` prefix that is used in the `CREATE TABLE ` snippet